# Doing <input disabled="disabled"/> or other boolean attribute in TAL

Tags: plone, template-tal, zpt

How one does attributes which may or may not exist? Exampls are checkbox checked="checked" or disabled="disabled" HTML attributes.

What kind of tal:attributes expression is involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an attribute listed in `tal:attributes` is set to None, the attribute is omitted:

```
<span tal:attributes="title python:len(item['title']) < 10 and item['title'] or None">
   Only a title if shorter than 10 characters.
</span>
```

The same applies to a path expression to a non-existing object:

```
<span tal:attributes="title item/title" />
```

Now the `title` attribute will only be set if there *is* a title key or attribute on item. Note that if `item/title` resolves to `None`, the attribute is omitted as well.

From the [TALES 1.4 specification, `attributes` section](http://wiki.zope.org/ZPT/TALSpecification14#attributes):

> If the expression associated with an attribute assignment evaluates to nothing, then that attribute is deleted from the statement element.

Where python `None` is interpreted as "nothing".